# Boto3 to list all the roles used by windows instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to print the role used by windows instances. what changes should I do in this script??

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id="",aws_secret_access_key="")
roles = client.list_roles()
Role_list = roles['Roles']
   for key in Role_list:
        print(key['RoleName'])
        print(key['Arn'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a program you could instead use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filter Name=platform,Values=windows \
--query Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,IamInstanceProfile.Arn] \
--output text
```

Output:

```
i-0ef605853b22abcd  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/My-Role
```